# How to fetch liferay entity through custom-finder in custom plugin portlet?

Tags: sql, service, liferay, liferay-6, builder

How can we fetch liferay entities through custom-finder using custom SQL?

1. Following is my sql query written in `default.xml` (<sub>I have trimmed down the query to the bare minimum so that the logic remains simple. Since it included a few functions and joins we couldn't use `DynamicQuery` API</sub> ):

   ```sql
   SELECT
       grp.*
   FROM
       Group_
   WHERE
       site = 1
       AND active_ = 1
       AND type_ <> 3
   ```
2. Relevant code in `MyCustomGroupFinderImpl.java`:

   ```java
   Session session = null;

   try {
       session = openSession();

       // fetches the query string from the default.xml
       String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_ONLY_ACTIVE_SITES);

       SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

       sqlQuery.addEntity("Group_", GroupImpl.class);
       // sqlQuery.addEntity("Group_", PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl"));

       return (List<Group>) QueryUtil.list(sqlQuery, getDialect(), 0, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       throw new SystemException(e);
   }
   finally {
       closeSession(session);
   }
   ```

This above code won't work as the `GroupImpl` class is present in `portal-impl.jar` and this jar cannot be used in custom portlet.

I also tried using `sqlQuery.addEntity("Group_", PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl"))`
But this above code throws exception:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException:
    com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException:
        org.hibernate.MappingException:
            Unknown entity: com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl
```

But the same code works for our custom-entity, if we write `sqlQuery.addEntity("MyCustomGroup", MyCustomGroupImpl.class);`.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out from the [liferay forum thread](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/7158040#_19_message_7166735) that instead of `session = openSession();`
we would need to fetch the session from `liferaySessionFactory` as follows to make it work:

```java
// fetch liferay's session factory
SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate("liferaySessionFactory");

Session session = null;

try {
    // open session using liferay's session factory
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    // fetches the query string from the default.xml
    String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_ONLY_ACTIVE_SITES);

    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

    // use portal class loader, since this is portal entity
    sqlQuery.addEntity("Group_", PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl"));

    return (List<Group>) QueryUtil.list(sqlQuery, getDialect(), 0, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SystemException(e);
}
finally {
    sessionFactory.closeSession(session); // edited as per the comment on this answer
    // closeSession(session);
}
```

Hope this helps somebody on stackoverflow, also I found a nice [tutorial](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/getting-data-from-multiple-tables-in.html) regarding custom-sql which also uses the same approach.

Comment: would that closeSession call on the finally block close that session? I looked at liferay's code and found it uses the sessionFactory of the finder to close the session hence my question.

Comment: @user1316487 I think it should be `sessionFactory.closeSession(session)` in this case. Thanks for pointing that out.