# Hibernate exceptions when accessing existing tables in liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay-6

I am using custom query to access exiting entities in liferay. Since I dont have new entities so I create a class as follows:

```
public class TestServiceBuilderPortlet {

    public static List<JournalArticle> getList() {
        List<JournalArticle> jaList = null;

        // fetch liferay's session factory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate("liferaySessionFactory");
        Session session = null;
        SQLQuery query = null;

        try {

            session = sessionFactory.openSession(); // Line A

            query = session.createSQLQuery("select {ja.*} from journalarticle as ja");

            query.setCacheable(false);

            query.addEntity("JournalArticle", PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.impl.JournalArticleImpl"));

            QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);

            jaList = query.list();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) sessionFactory.closeSession(session);
        }

        return jaList;
    }
}
```

When I called the above function I got exceptions: "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"

I got the above code based on some sources:

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/7158040#_19_message_7166735

[How to fetch liferay entity through custom-finder in custom plugin portlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895484/how-to-fetch-liferay-entity-through-custom-finder-in-custom-plugin-portlet)

I also search for the above exception and there is one workaround: adding `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` to portal-ext.properties but it did work for me.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create blank entity in service.xml and in XXXLocalServiceImpl.java, you can add method with your code(getting records from db), you will not get error about hibernate session then. Basically this class privides necessary hibernate session.