# how to get result persist result in our POJO class or wrapper through custom finder in Liferay

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay

How can we fetch the result of Custom SQL run through Custom finder directly into our POJO class or Wrapper?

As explained in below question:

[How to fetch liferay entity through custom-finder in custom plugin portlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895484/how-to-fetch-liferay-entity-through-custom-finder-in-custom-plugin-portlet)

we can fetch result into liferay entity using below code

```
// use portal class loader, since this is portal entity
sqlQuery.addEntity("Group_", PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.liferay.portal.model.impl.GroupImpl"));
```

the same code works for our custom-entity if we write

```
sqlQuery.addEntity("MyCustomGroup", MyCustomGroupImpl.class);
```

But we can use custom entity only when we have built it using service builder **service.xml** build and doing so will create the table for each custom entity in the table.sql file of service builder plugin project.

I don't want to create the separate table for each custom entity. That's the reason I have created java wrapper class and want to inject the result directly into my wrapper class. I don't want to iterate the result set of custom query. Is there any way to do so?